# Spring - Ways to include a jar which itself is using Spring in a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, dependency-injection, java-ee-6

I need to use some 3rd party jar in my project. **The project is a Spring project and the jar is also using Spring.**

Is there a way by which I can include the 3rd party jar in my project? I am finding it difficult to find each and every dependency of the 3rd part jar and inject it.

Comment: I guess the third party jar doesn't have a pom.xml. Maybe it has another build script that could help. Or maybe it documents its dependencies somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. Application contexts can be loaded independent of one another in the same JVM, generally. But if you're loading your bean definitions from a resource file in the classpath (e.g. using **ClasspathXmlApplicationContext**), make sure the location and name of your file does not conflict with the third-party JAR. For example, if they're both located at "/applicationContext.xml" in different JARs in the classpath, you will have a problem. Make yours unique.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear exactly what you mean by "include".

If the 3rd party jar is defined as a dependency in your war project, it will automatically be bundled into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war when it is packaged by the [war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). Any class in the jar would then be on the classpath and therefore available to be referenced in your Spring configuration. Do you have a more specific requirement than this?

Also note that if the 3rd-party jar is a properly-defined Maven project, it's dependencies will be defined in its pom. Those transitive dependencies are also bundled into the war (unless you have them defined with a non-default [scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) in which case they might not be).

Any of the jars you find on the Maven central repository *should* be defined with all their transitive dependencies. If you're having trouble resolving them, please update your answer so that the relevant Maven credentials can be located.

Update based on your comment. Once the jar is on the war's classpath, you can reference any Spring configuration files it declares by importing them into your war's application context. You just specify the import in the form: "jar:file://jarName!/path/to/config.xml"

Comment: How are you expecting that loading my-project's application context will actually load the 3rd party jars application context? This is my problem..

Comment: you didn't mention the any spring configuration in your question, so I wasn't expecting it at all. I've updated my answer to show how the configuration file in the 3rd party jar could be imported into you war's configuration

Comment: Thanks Rich. +1 for the last part of the answer. BTW, do we have more *ways* to handle this. Just want to know all the ways :)

Comment: The only other ways I know involve writing your own configuration processing. I don't think there is a means to auto-discover configuration if that is what you're after.